# Getting NullPointerException when referencing my Stage from my Controller class in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, reference, controller, fxml

So, I have an application with a few fxml files.  One of the fxml creates a scene that is a different size than all the others, and I would like for it to load the window to match the scene size.

What I have done is referenced the stage in my `HumansightExecutiveController.java` class with `Stage stage = (Stage) humansightExecutivePane.getScene().getWindow();` in my initialize function for said controller class.  Also in this initialize function is `stage.sizeToScene`, which produces a NullPointerException error.  I'm unsure as to why this is happening as the previous line getting the window is does not produce an error.

## My code:

### HumansightExecutiveController.java

```java
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HumansightExecutiveController implements Initializable{

    @FXML 
    private AnchorPane humansightExecutivePane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) humansightExecutivePane.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.sizeToScene();
    }
}
```

### Main.java

```java
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            // Load FXML file
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ExecutivePromptXML.fxml"));

            // Create scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 600);

            // Load CSS
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

            // Display application
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

### ExecutiveLoginController.java

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class ExecutiveLoginController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane loginPane;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @FXML
    private void loginReturn(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ExecutivePromptXML.fxml"));
        loginPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }

    @FXML
    private void authenticate(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("HumansightExecutiveXML.fxml"));
        loginPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }
}
```

### Error:

The three warnings at the top happen even when the application is working fine.  They have always happened, so I don't think they are relevant.

```
Jan 27, 2019 3:55:20 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.191
Jan 27, 2019 3:55:22 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.191
Jan 27, 2019 3:55:23 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.191
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/student/Desktop/Humansight/EclipseEnvironment/humansightExecutiveFirstDraft/bin/application/HumansightExecutiveXML.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.ExecutiveLoginController.authenticate(ExecutiveLoginController.java:32)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.HumansightExecutiveController.initialize(HumansightExecutiveController.java:18)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 63 more
```

I would like to clarify that my question is *not* about what a NullPointerException is.  My question is why my `stage` variable is null despite getting no NPE when initializing it.

### Let me know if any more information is needed and thank you.

Comment: My guess is that your code is "pointing" to something that is "null" (ie: doesn't exist). Is your `stage` or its `Scene` null?

Comment: @Zephyr That was the first thing I checked and that's what my question is asking.  I understand that I am looking for why my stage is null.  Based on the fact that the `Stage stage = ...` line ran successfully, the only way that stage could be null is if somehow `getWindow()` returned null, but I would still expect an error if that were the case.  I am pretty sure `Scene` is not null, because it is in the `initialize()` function, which should mean that the scene is fully loaded by the time the method runs.

Comment: `getWindow()` could successfully return `null` if the stage exists but the `Window`  has not been rendered/displayed yet. Try adding the method call in a `Platform.runLater()` block; you're calling it from the `initialize()` method, which is run before the stage is shown, therefore, there is no `Window` yet.

Comment: @Zephyr I will look deeper into `getWindow()` then.  The fxml does not render/display, but I think (might be wrong) that putting things in the `initialize()` function should mean the `Scene` is created by the time the method is called.

Comment: The `Scene` is created, yes. But the `Window` is not, because there's no window being displayed yet :)

Comment: @Zephyr Interesting.  Any ideas why that might happen?

Comment: That is just how JavaFX works.

Comment: Counting the lines in the code you posted, the line causing the NPE is `Stage stage = (Stage) humansightExecutivePane.getScene().getWindow();` not the following line. The `Scene` is not even created when `FXMLLoader.load` completes which happens after `initialize` is called for the controller.

Comment: @fabian  Oops, I will edit my post to show the code that loads this scene.  There is a scene the user goes through before this in which a button loads the new fxml.  The method is the one called `authenticate()`. Thanks.

Comment: @Zephyr The `Platform.runLater()` method worked!  Thank you!  If you want the reputation you can type it out as an official answer and I will click the accept button.

Comment: Not necessary, as there are already good answers on this elsewhere :)